# C# threading incrementing an integer higher than expected

Tags: c#, multithreading

Firstly I want to apologize for my program only being half done, but I want to try and fix the problem before I continue with the program.

The following in my entire solution thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;

        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap("test.jpg");

        Bitmap returnImg = new Bitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pic);

        Color clr;
        int[] argb = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < pic.Width; i++) // pic.Width = 50
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < pic.Height; k++) // pic.Height = 50
            {
                clr = pic.GetPixel(i, k);
                argb[0] = clr.A;
                argb[1] = clr.R;
                argb[2] = clr.G;
                argb[3] = clr.B;


                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    if (k < 50)
                    {
                        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, INTEGER K STILL GETS THE VALUE 50 ASSIGNED TO IT.
                        g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(getBestPic(argb)), new Point(i, k));
                    }
                }).Start();

            }
        }
        returnImg = new Bitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height, g);
        returnImg.Save("createdImage.jpg");
    }

    //Get picture that is best suited to replace pixel
    private string getBestPic(int[] argb)
    {
        int numOfpics = 5;
        int[] currentBest = new int[2];
        currentBest[0] = 255;
        currentBest[1] = 150;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfpics; i++)
        {
            int compare = compareARGB(getAverageRGB(new Bitmap((i + 1).ToString()+".jpg")), argb);
            if (compare < currentBest[0])
            {
                currentBest[0] = compare;
                currentBest[1] = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return currentBest[1].ToString() + ".jpg";
    }

    // smaller the value, closer the camparison
    private int compareARGB(int[] one, int[] two)
    {
        int [] tmp = new int[4];
        tmp[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(one[0] - two[0]));
        tmp[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(one[1] - two[1]));
        tmp[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(one[2] - two[2]));
        tmp[3] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(one[3] - two[3]));

        return (tmp[0] + tmp[1] + tmp[2] + tmp[3]);
    }

    //return int arry with size 4 contaning the argb values
    private int[] getAverageRGB(Bitmap img)
    {
        Color clr;
        int aplha = 0;
        int red = 0;
        int green = 0;
        int blue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < img.Height; k++)
            {
                clr = img.GetPixel(i, k);
                aplha += clr.A;
                red += clr.R;
                green += clr.G;
                blue += clr.B;
            }
        }

        aplha = aplha / (img.Width * img.Height);
        red = red / (img.Width * img.Height);
        green = green / (img.Width * img.Height);
        blue = blue / (img.Width * img.Height);

        int[] re = new int[] {aplha,red,green,blue};

        return re;
    }
}
}
```

This is a montage program I am creating. I am comparing each pixel rgb of the main picture with the average rgb of the list of thumbnails. The thumbnail with an average rgb closes to the pixel rgb is used to replace the pixel.

I already know there is going to be a lot of criticism of my program. I know the resolution of the resulting picture is going to be huge ens.

The only issue I want help with is why integer k in button1_Click function is increasing to the value 50, when there is a check for less than 50 in the thread and the for loop k should not go to 50. THIS ISSUE DOES NOT OCCUR WHEN I TAKE THE THREADING OUT AND IT HAPPENS RANDOMLY. The value of integer i varies when my program breaks (because k gets assigned to the value 50). That is why I cannot use break point or step through my program. Because this happen randomly, when there are already a lot of the threads created.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue results from the fact that C# closures capture the variable itself, *not* its value. This combined with the scoping of the for-loop variable prior to C# 5.0 mean that the value of `k` seen by the code running on a separate thread will change as the loop on the main thread iterates through its values, and in your case most importantly, can change between the `if (k < 50)` check and the subsequent use of `k`. MSDN describes the changes in C# 5.0 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh678682(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you catch it at just the right moment, the value of `k` can increment from 50 to 51 as a result of the for-loop on its final iteration just *after* the `if (k < 50)` check but *before* the if-statement body.

As a result of this same issue, you'll probably also find that some values of `k` will be skipped, and some processed multiple times by different threads.

To resolve this you need to assign `k` to a local variable and capture that instead. Since the variable `localK` is local to that iteration of the loop, the captured value does not change within the thread:

```
            ...
            var localK = k;
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                if (localK < 50)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(getBestPic(argb)), new Point(i, localK));
                }
            }).Start();
            ...
```

It's worth adding that it's practically guaranteed that running this in a threaded manner will drastically *reduce* performance the overhead of creating and switching between 2500 threads will far outweigh any benefit that might be gained from parallel processing.

Comment: precisely what is stated above. +1

Comment: @user2106301 whilst it might work with the change I indicated, it seems unlikely that it'll be faster than doing it single-threaded (and may indeed be *much slower*).

Comment: Could be. As soon as I get the threading 100% correct, I will see which one is better or faster. Next step for me is to do something about the threads using g.DrawImage simultaneous. It results in an "Object is currently in use elsewhere." exception for obvious reasons. So now i will see which is the best why to handle that. Use locks or change the way I use the treading.

Comment: Just another side note. This is in the very early stages of this program and this is a side project for me. So there will still be a lot of changes to this program. This is only for fun and learning pitfalls of threading. I really appreciate the help. I will later add the functionality to limit the number of threads